# Override Maven's download of a 3rd party software with a local copy?

Tags: node.js, maven, jenkins, 32-bit

I am running the 32-bit build of Ubuntu 18.04 and attempting to build a 32-bit Jenkins from the source.
It fails in the last stage (see below) because it cannot find a Linux x86 build of Nodejs. They don't make 32-bit versions for Linux anymore. I'm fine with that - I have downloaded the 14.15.4 Nodejs sources and built my own 32-bit version. How can I override the Jenkins maven build that is attempting to download a non-existent package directly from the Nodejs distribution site?
I have tried prepositioning my home-built node-14.15.4-linux-x86.tar.gz in the appropriate location, but the build is getting killed because the package does not exist on the website it is attempting to download from (404 - Not Found).  If I could stop it trying to download or tell it to pull the .tar.gz package from the local filesystem, I think that should fix the problem. I haven't found anything online and maven configurations are completely foreign to me.

```
[INFO] Installing node version v14.15.4
[INFO] Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.4/node-v14.15.4-linux-x86.tar.gz to /home/scott/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/node/14.15.4/node-14.15.4-linux-x86.tar.gz
[INFO] No proxies configured
[INFO] No proxy was configured, downloading directly
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Jenkins main module 2.275-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] Jenkins main module ................................ SUCCESS [  4.868 s]
[INFO] Jenkins BOM ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.156 s]
[INFO] Jenkins cli ........................................ SUCCESS [ 10.285 s]
[INFO] Jenkins core ....................................... SUCCESS [01:12 min]
[INFO] Jenkins war ........................................ FAILURE [  4.536 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:35 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-08T00:47:30-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.11.0:install-node-and-yarn (install node and yarn) on project jenkins-war: Could not download Node.js: Got error code 404 from the server. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project?

Comment: I don't think the reference is applicable because my issue is that the existing maven config is actually pulling a file from a foreign, non-maven repo.  It is actually looking for the executable Nodejs tar file and expanding it directly in the temporary build directories. Because the -linux-x86 architecture version does not exist on the source website, the download returns a 404 and kills the build.

Comment: The question I linked above has answers that explain how to use a local JAR with maven.

Comment: Workaround was to modify the appropriate POM file to use the last official 32-bit build.